# shell replace cr\lf by comma

Tags: bash, shell, newline, text-processing

I have input.txt

```
1
2
3
4
5
```

I need to get such output.txt

```
1,2,3,4,5
```

How to do it?

Comment: What line ending should the output have?  You mention CR\LF in the question - you mean that you have a DOS text file?  And the output should be a DOS text file (so you need a final CRLF)?

Answer (score 119, accepted):

Try this:

```
tr '\n' ',' < input.txt > output.txt
```

Comment: This deals with the newlines; what about the carriage returns?  There might be nothing to do if the user is on DOS and it is a text file - the input routines convert CRLF to '\n'.  More seriously, perhaps, the code replaces the final newline (CRLF) with a comma.

Comment: This solution leaves a comma at the end:

Comment: just as a reply to Jonathon's question, I had to replace `'\n'` with `'\r'` for carriage return.

Comment: If you have both `\r` and `\n` in there, you can use `dos2unix` to strip carriage returns and then apply this `tr` for `\n`s.

Comment: This simple command just saved me a bunch of time by converting the output of one SQL query into CSV instead of using an subquery with an `IN` statement :)

Comment: @NestorUrquiza This is because of the POSIX rule of what a line is: _A sequence of zero or more non- <newline> characters plus a terminating <newline> character._ (See [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/729692)). Hence this is not the best answer. Your [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/32487078/8344060) using `paste` overcomes this.

Answer (score 25):

With `sed`, you could use:

```
sed -e 'H;${x;s/\n/,/g;s/^,//;p;};d'
```

The `H` appends the pattern space to the hold space (saving the current line in the hold space).  The `${...}` surrounds actions that apply to the last line only.  Those actions are: `x` swap hold and pattern space; `s/\n/,/g` substitute embedded newlines with commas; `s/^,//` delete the leading comma (there's a newline at the start of the hold space); and `p` print.  The `d` deletes the pattern space - no printing.

You could also use, therefore:

```
sed -n -e 'H;${x;s/\n/,/g;s/^,//;p;}'
```

The `-n` suppresses default printing so the final `d` is no longer needed.

This solution assumes that the CRLF line endings are the local native line ending (so you are working on DOS) and that `sed` will therefore generate the local native line ending in the print operation.  If you have DOS-format input but want Unix-format (LF only) output, then you have to work a bit harder - but you also need to stipulate this explicitly in the question.

It worked OK for me on MacOS X 10.6.5 with the numbers 1..5, and 1..50, and 1..5000 (23,893 characters in the single line of output); I'm not sure that I'd want to push it any harder than that.

Comment: Another way: `sed -n ':a;N;${s/\n/,/g;p};ba'` (without having to get rid of a leading comma).

Answer (score 21):

In response to @Jonathan's comment to @eumiro's answer:

```
tr -s '\r\n' ',' < input.txt | sed -e 's/,$/\n/' > output.txt
```

Answer (score 13):

`tr` and `sed` used be very good but when it comes to file parsing and regex you can't beat perl 
(Not sure why people think that sed and tr are closer to shell than perl... )

```
perl -pe 's/\n/$1,/' your_file
```

if you want pure shell to do it then look at string matching

```
${string/#substring/replacement}
```

Comment: +1 because tr replaces all the characters so was no good for me and the sed solution worked if you cat a file but failed for some reason if you `tail -f` a file

Answer (score 13):

Use paste command. Here is using pipes:

```
echo "1\n2\n3\n4\n5" | paste -s -d, /dev/stdin
```

Here is using a file:

```
echo "1\n2\n3\n4\n5" > /tmp/input.txt
paste -s -d, /tmp/input.txt
```

Per man pages the s concatenates all lines and d allows to define the delimiter character.

Answer (score 12):

- **Awk versions:**

  - `awk '{printf("%s,",$0)}' input.txt`
  - `awk 'BEGIN{ORS=","} {print $0}' input.txt`
  - Output - `1,2,3,4,5,`

Since you asked for `1,2,3,4,5`, as compared to `1,2,3,4,5,` (note the comma after 5, most of the solutions above also include the trailing comma), here are two more versions with Awk (with `wc` and `sed`) to get rid of the last comma:

- `i='input.txt'; awk -v c=$(wc -l $i | cut -d' ' -f1) '{printf("%s",$0);if(NR<c){printf(",")}}' $i`
- `awk '{printf("%s,",$0)}' input.txt | sed 's/,\s*$//'`

Answer (score 7):

```
printf "1\n2\n3" | tr '\n' ','
```

if you want to output that to a file just do

```
printf "1\n2\n3" | tr '\n' ',' > myFile
```

if you have the content in a file do

```
cat myInput.txt | tr '\n' ',' > myOutput.txt
```

Answer (score 2):

- **python version:**

  `python -c 'import sys; print(",".join(sys.stdin.read().splitlines()))'`

Doesn't have the trailing comma problem (because `join` works that way), and `splitlines` splits data on native line endings (and removes them).

Answer (score 0):

```
cat input.txt | sed -e 's|$|,|' | xargs -i echo "{}"
```